# What happens if you have :base() in the top class?

Tags: c#, constructor, this, program-entry-point, radix

I am having problems understanding what happens if you put the :base() in top class. The code goes like this...

```
class A {
 public A(): this(3) {
  Console.Write("1");
 }
 public A(int x): base() {
  Console.Write("{0}", x);
 }
}

class B:A {
 public B(): this(4) {
Console.Write("3");
 }
 public B(int x) {
  Console.Write("{0}", x):
 }
}

class C:B {
 public C(int x): base() {
  Console.Write("{0}", x):
 }
 public C(): this(7) {
  Console.Write("6");
 }
}

class Program {
 public static void Main(string[] args) {
   C c = new C();
  }
```

I don't get why we need to start from the top (class A). So what would be the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top classes inherit implicitly from `System.Object` (C# alias `object`). So this basically calls the default constructor of `object`. But since the default constructor of the base class is called by default anyway, this doesn't change anything.

So

```
public A(int x)
    : base()
{
}
```

and

```
public A(int x)
{
}
```

are equivalent.

If a base class constructor has parameters, then you must call it explicitly to pass the required parameters.

See: [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)

Answer (score 4):

All classes inherit from the `System.Object` class by default so when adding `base()` in the top class `A`, you are calling the constructor of the object class, this will cause nothing.

Comment: @SrđanTodorović [This](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,45) is how the constructor looks like.